# GREP PCRE RegExp: match desired line, then match the number, then remove the commas to match digits only

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, pcregrep

With the help of https://regexr.com/ I'm trying to understand and learn `grep -P`.

So far I managed to get this result:

```
$ cat Dogtooth\ \[2001\,\ Lanthimos\ Yorgos\].mp4.info
Filename:               Dogtooth [2001, Lanthimos Yorgos].mp4
Title:                  Κυνόδοντας
File size:              4,240,762,886 bytes
Video duration:         5,839 seconds
```

I'm successful in getting the value of *Filename* with `^F\w+\:\s+\K.+\.\w{1,4}$`

```
$ grep -o -P '^F\w+\:\s+\K.+\.\w{1,4}$' Dogtooth\ \[2001\,\ Lanthimos\ Yorgos\].mp4.info
```

outputs to `Dogtooth [2001, Lanthimos Yorgos].mp4`

Yay!! :D

But now comes the headache...

I can't get value of *File size*

Original string:

- `File size:              4,240,762,886 bytes`

Expected result:

- `4240762886`

I only managed to get this far (matching the digits): `(^.*size\:\s+\b)\K(\d.+\d)`

But I still miss how to get get rid of those damn *commas*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you can't use just grep to do this:

```bash
grep -P -o 'File size:\s+\K[\d,]+' file.info | tr -d ,
```

```
4240762886
```

The `-o` option outputs only the matched text not the whole line.

Comment: _The -o option outputs only the matched text not the whole line._ <- I **want** `grep` to output matched text only. So sad I cannot use `grep` alone... Thanks for `tr` suggestion anyway ;)

Comment: @T.Caio, mm, isn't that `4240762886` here what you showed in the question as the output you wanted? If that's not it, you might want to [edit the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/714879/edit) to show what it is you actually want as the output.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes! `4240762886` is the output I want, but I was looking for a solution via `pcregrep` only ;)

Comment: @T.Caio, one word: _why_?

Comment: @T.Caio Okay, more words: is there some particular reason you'd want to use `pcregrep` only, and specifically just that? As shown here, it'd be easier with a combination of tools (or a wholly other tool), and it doesn't seem like you could very easily do something else with the same invocation of `pcregrep` anyway. So that just makes it sound like an arbitrary restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -F':' '{tag=$1; sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,"")} tag=="Filename"' file
Dogtooth [2001, Lanthimos Yorgos].mp4

$ awk -F':' '{tag=$1; sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,"")} tag=="Title"' file
Κυνόδοντας

$ awk -F':' '{tag=$1; sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,"")} tag=="File size"{gsub(/,| .*/,""); print}' file
4240762886

$ awk -F':' '{tag=$1; sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,"")} tag=="Video duration"{gsub(/,| .*/,""); print}' file
5839
```

Remember the quote: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).